# Changing the password, revoking the access of Application in Gmail

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

We are using the refresh token to get Google Calendar free/busy events. When our application connects with Google account of a user for the first time, we obtain a "Refresh Token" and store that in our database and use that for fetching free/busy events from Google. Things were working fine but now the problem is that whenever a user changes its Gmail password then we're unable to call the Google Api using the stored refresh token. The reason we've have found is that Google revokes the Api access for all applications associated to that account on password change/reset. In our application, calendar is still connected to Google (because we do not make call to reconnect with google again). How can we check/identify if the stored Refresh token is still valid or not? Is there any suggested workaround for this problem?

Comment: " Google revokes the Api access for all applications associated to that account on password change/reset" yeah its a new feature.    The only way to test if your refresh token still works is to try and get a new access token if it fails well you will need to ask for access again.

Comment: Is Google suggested any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Nope the point is that if the user changes there password you should be forced to reauthentciate.  There wont be a work around.  It was what they wanted to happen.   http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.dk/2015/12/increased-account-security-via-oauth2.html